# I have created a swift Framework but it shows error while accessing the Classes

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am using Xcode 7.2 and I have created a swift framework, I can import the framework without error but cannon access the class files of my framework.[image]

In the DropDown class file set as public

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Dropdown class is not exposed publicly or just check it is linked properly..

Comment: Yes it is exposed publicly, how can I check its linked properly?
however I can also see my public methods in the framework header.

Comment: are you able to get the instance like this    let dropdown : DropDown !?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your DropDown class is defined as public
`public class DropDown`

Comment: Is the swift file with your dropdown class included in dropdown framework  target?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if the `init()` in the `DropDown` class is marked as public

Comment: Yes the init() is also set as public.